# Let me know if i can optimize this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

does anybody have any suggestions to optimize this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(client_id) FROM (
  SELECT client_id FROM `cdr` WHERE 
    (DATE(start) BETWEEN '2014-04-21' AND '2014-04-25') AND 
    `service` = 'test' 
    GROUP BY client_id  
    HAVING SUM(duration) > 300 
)as t1
```

The problem is , inner query scans millions of rows and returns thousands of rows and it makes main query lazy.

Thanks.

Comment: How does the execution plan look like?

Comment: What is the type of `start` datetime ?

Comment: @Mostafa-T: You can try query suggested by me, it can be further optimized if you show your desired results.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid , yes it's datetime.

Comment: @Mostafa-T your query is not [**SARGABLE**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) even if you have an index on your datetime too using date function will force this to ignore index the answer suggested by Zafar Malik will use index if you have so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below query, avoid functions in searching as it does not use index and kill the performance. "start" columns must be indexed.

```
SELECT COUNT(client_id) FROM (
  SELECT client_id FROM `cdr` WHERE 
    (start BETWEEN '2014-04-21 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-25 23:59:59') AND 
    `service` = 'test' 
    GROUP BY client_id  
    HAVING SUM(duration) > 300 
)as t1
```

Comment: `start >= '2014-04-21' AND start < '2014-04-26'`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yes it will give same results and mysql suggest use of >= and <= operator instead of between...but as per my experiance there minor difference which will not even we notice. But yes we should use it as mysql suggest and at least does not down performance and chances are to improve.. but here main reason of performance degrade is date function..so I suggest him this. Even query can be further optimized after removing sub-query but if user share his desired result.

Comment: One second, it is very long period to have wrong query :)

Comment: @ZafarMalik : Your query just returns thousands of rows , which I've had before, I want COUNT of those rows instead of rows. In my query sub-query returns same rows and the main query calculate COUNT of those rows. I'm looking for another query to combine these two queries.

Comment: @Mostafa-T overall query will give you count as sub-query get all users with your condition and having sum(duration)>300 and then main query will provide you count of these users...same as your query..but this query should be faster than you...Is it not.

Comment: @zafarmalik , Furthermore I've read an article in mysql.com about avoiding use of parenthesis in queries. may be it could be better to rewrite the start condition without parenthesis.

Comment: We should not use access/un-neccesory use of them but it is good to use them to make query clear for an example it is necessary in case of combination of AND and OR...I am not getting any issue here means you can keep or remove..but yes as @HamletHakobyan suggested above in his comment you can change between with > and <.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?I have read somewhere that comparing dates directly with < or > works faster than Between.

```
SELECT Count(client_id) FROM `cdr` 
WHERE DATE(start) >=  '2014-04-21' 
    AND DATE(start) <= '2014-04-25'
    AND  `service` = 'test' 
GROUP BY client_id  
HAVING SUM(duration) > 300
```

What was logic behind having sub query in your sql?

Comment: This query returns thousands of rows , which I've had before, I want COUNT of those rows instead of rows so I added another query to calculate COUNT of those rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can use direct query instead of sub query like as

```
SELECT COUNT(client_id) FROM `cdr` 
WHERE (DATE(start) BETWEEN '2014-04-21' AND '2014-04-25') 
    AND `service` = 'test' 
GROUP BY client_id  
HAVING SUM(duration) > 300
```